# Angular - Input [value] bound to form control is not refreshing once with the form control value

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

In a reactive form approach, I have a slider which has a form control bound to it. When the slider is moves the form control value updates. 
I also have an input field near the slider which shows the value of the slider and can also update it by typing.

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="{{feature.name}}-input"
                [min]="0" [max]="100" [step]="1"
                (change)="onInputChange($event, feature)" [value]="featuresForm.get(feature.name)?.value.value">
```

And I have the following `onInputChange` method which updates the form control's value when the user changes the input:

```
onInputChange(event: any, feature: any) {
const input = this.featuresForm.get(feature.name);

if (event.target.value > 100) {
  input?.setValue({ value: 100 });
  return;
}
if (event.target.value < 0) {
  input?.setValue({ value: 0 });
  return;
}

input?.setValue({ value: event.target.value });
  }
```

Everything works fine if I input value between the 0 and 100, but something strange happens if I input values outside of that range.

For example:

1. Input 105 - input value resets to 100
2. Input 110 - input value stays at 110(or any other value that you type over 100), it does not reset anymore
3. Input 50 - input value resets to 50, everything work as expected

I think that by executing `input?.setValue({ value: 100 });` in a consecutive manner, input 105 and then 110, the form will not detect any change and it will therefore not update `[value]="featuresForm.get(feature.name)?.value.value"`. Is there a way to fix this?

Edit: 
Stackblitz url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yb2vgj

Please assume that the first input would be a slider which has an input of type

```
new FormControl({value: 24}), and not new FormControl(24)
```

With the code that is present there and with the scenario posted above I would like to understand why the second input does not update properly after 2 consecutive inputs of over 100.

Comment: Use ngModel for two way binding

Comment: @SanjayLohar Or even better, use reactive forms the way they're meant to be used - with `formControlName`

Comment: @KurtHamilton yeah thats a better option.

Comment: Well, there's a reason I coded it like that. The slider(which has a `formControlName`) has a value of type `value: {value: 1}` while the input has a value of type `value: 1`. To have the input have the same value as the slider that is what I came up with.

Comment: can you please create a stackblitz instance for this ?

Comment: @JasdeepSingh I've edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can resolve it via many hacks, please find the below code. You can create an another property that will keep track of input form. We can use this property to update the slider form control value as well.

I hope it will help else i will recommend you to create a stackblitz instance.

```js
myInputValue = 0;
onInputChange(event: any, feature: any) {
  const input = this.featuresForm.get(feature.name);

  this.myInputValue = (event.target.value > 100) ? 100 :
    (event.target.value < 0)? 0:
    event.target.value;

  input ? .setValue({
    value: this.myInputValue;
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="{{feature.name}}-input" [min]="0" [max]="100" [step]="1" (change)="onInputChange($event, feature)" [value]="myInputValue">
```

You can also use setTimeout to forcefully initiate change detection.

```
onInputChange(event: any) {
    debugger;
    if (event.target.value > 100) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.featuresForm.get('slider').setValue(100)
        return;
      })
    }
    if (event.target.value < 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.featuresForm.get('slider').setValue(0)
      return;
      })
    }

    this.featuresForm.get('slider').setValue( event.target.value )
  }
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your solution. Having a bound variable may indeed work, but I would like to understand what is happening in my scenario. I've also posted a stackblitz instance.

Comment: You are using property binding to get the value property of second input [value]="featuresForm.get(feature.name)?.value.value". Angular updates binding whenever their is any change in model. But in your case there is no change in model as you are setting it to same value of 100 at second time as well. So, it is not updating. The code provided by me would be an ideal solution else you can also use setTimeout. I am updating my solution with setTimout solution as well. I have created a group to chat if you want to.

Comment: Yes, I've also suspected that by updating the form input with the same value the change will not be detected. I will give the angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef approach another try to see if I can force a change detection run.

Comment: Unfortunately `ChangeDetectorRef` does not work. I will accept the answer as having a class variable would work, but I will keep looking if there's a way to have my way working - maybe force a form detection change or something.

Comment: Just wanted to know if you got any success using other way, could you please share with me.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only solution that worked was to add a formControl for the input as well and keep both of them in sync. Everything else that I've tried would result in the same bug.

Comment: I did try for next two days, but believe me running change detection manually is not a good idea. Adding a form control is also a nice way to accomplish the task